# What does lags mean exactly in XGBoost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm trying to make a time series forecast using XGBoost,  I didn't understood very well the meaning of lags:

1. What does it do and meaning of it?
2. what is the best way to choose the more efficient lag parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lags` in the context of forecasting are data points that happened before a fixed amount of time.

For example:

You have a dataset with monthly data, let's say **from 01/09/2023 to 30/09/2023**;

`lag = 7d` would mean data points from **25/08/2023 to 23/09/2023** are used to predict the data in September.

Answering your 2nd question, what is the best way to choose -- `15m`, `30m`, `1h`, `6h`, `12h`, `1d`, `7d`, `30d`, `60d`, `90d`, and even `180d` lags, depending on the **frequency** of the target variable.